# Retirar trecho de uma string

Tags: php, string

tenho uma string, exemplo:

```
32137hyb8bhbhu837218nhbuhuh&3298j19j2n39
```

Eu quero retirar(limpar) da string tudo que vier depois do `&`.

Por favor, como fazer isso?

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strstr.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode utilizar a função [explode](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php) para fazer isto.

```
$str = "32137hyb8bhbhu837218nhbuhuh&3298j19j2n39";
$str = explode("&",$str);
echo $str[0];
```

Que tem como saída

```
32137hyb8bhbhu837218nhbuhuh
```

### Explicação

A função `explode` divide uma string pelo separador dado e retorna um array contendo as partes separadas.
Desde modo ela divide a string `32137hyb8bhbhu837218nhbuhuh&3298j19j2n39` em duas partes `32137hyb8bhbhu837218nhbuhuh` e `3298j19j2n39` e guarda cada parte em um índice do array. A parte que vc precisa pode ser acessada no primeiro índice do array, neste caso, `$str[0]`.

Pode ver funcionando online [aqui](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/83a1cb2be411c150bee7ded0979ad3514d1d790b)

Answer (score 5):

Pode usa função `strstr()` passando o terceiro argumento que retorna apenas a parte a esquerda do delimitador:

```
echo strstr('32137hyb8bhbhu837218nhbuhuh&3298j19j2n39', '&', true);
```

Retorna:

```
32137hyb8bhbhu837218nhbuhuh
```

Answer (score 4):

Tente isso:

```
$retorno = explode("&","32137hyb8bhbhu837218nhbuhuh&3298j19j2n39")[0];
```

[Veja Exemplo aqui](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp)

Answer (score 4):

Se tiver alguma preferencia por `REGEX`, o que acho difícil, poderia utilizar isto:

```
$string = '32137hyb8bhbhu837218nhbuhuh&3298j19j2n39';

preg_match('/(.*)&/', $string, $match);

echo $match[1];
```

Resposta:

```
32137hyb8bhbhu837218nhbuhuh
```

O [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php) utiliza o `REGEX` de `/(.*)&/` irá obter tudo (`.*`)  que for anterior ao `&`.

*Lembrando que é apenas mais um método alternativo aos métodos que já foram respondidos.*

Answer (score 4):

Acrescentando mais uma opção, você pode utilizar em uma única sequência a combinação das funções [`substr`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php) e [`strrpos`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strrpos.php):

```
$text = '32137hyb8bhbhu837218nhbuhuh&3298j19j2n39';
echo substr($text, 0, strrpos($text, '&'));
```

Resultando em:

```
32137hyb8bhbhu837218nhbuhuh
```

Confira no [ideone](http://ideone.com/RXXETm)